# Is it safe to pull out the purchase record stapled in my passport?

Tags: passports, japan, passport-stamps, duty-free

In Japan, duty free goods can be purchased not only at the airport, but also at the designated shops. The condition is simple, that you have a visitor visa, and if the goods are of "Consumable" category (e.g. food or cosmetics), you have to keep in within the sealed "tax-free" plastic bag until you get out of Japan.

However, **every time** you buy something, a shop will staple a purchase record in your passport (a white slip with information of the buyer, location of the shop, etc.). This ended up in 5 or 6 white slips in my passport, each slip covers 2 pages (!) See picture.
Those slips are eating up almost all the blank pages left in my passport, and even if they don't, they thickened up my passport significantly.

For example in the photo, it's been a year since I left Japan, sometimes I want to just pull out those slips, but as you see, there's a tiny red seal on it, overlapping both the slip and the passport page.

If I pull out the slips, there will be only halves of the seals on my "almost blank" passport pages. Is it safe to do that? I don't want to invite potential troubles, like, any embassy staff later might raise a question *"is there any problem with this passport, it **seems** that there are some records removed?"*

[image]

Comment: Seems not reasonable at all to force buyer to have these record in their passport till the passport expires. Had I buy stuffs at 3 or 4 more stores, the immigration officer at the airport when I came back would not be happy, as he won't find a blank page to put his stamp on. And what if I only have 1 or 2 blank pages left yet still want to buy more stuffs?

Comment: @fkraiem wow your comment is what I count as this :) http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/rude-pointless-or-lengthy-chats-in-comments?cb=1